# Active Directory Service Interface: what are the security guarantees of the communication channel used by each provider?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to figure out whether the communication channels used for the `WinNT://` and `LDAP://` providers are encrypted, or how to make sure they are, but cannot seem to find definitive information about it.

1. Does the `WinNT://` provider use any encryption at all?
2. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath) states:

   > The "PortNumber" specifies the port to be used for the connection. If no port number is specified, the LDAP provider uses the **default port number**. The default port number **is 389 if not using an SSL connection or 636 if using an SSL connection**.

   How do I make sure a SSL connection is used? Alternatively, is there any cons in specifying a server name directly, so I can be explicit about the port too, or does it perhaps even have benefits? I am wondering, since many of the examples I see don't specify a server at all.